# Can I calculate the probability of two dices using binomial coefficient?

Tags: probability

I'm completely new to probabilities and started working through a book on the subject.

The book presented an example of calculating probabilities using the binomial coefficient formula, but didn't really explain it fully.

The book used it together with this example:

*Imagine that you have 1 box with 20 glasses, 5 glasses are randomly picked and tested in the box. 4 of the 20 glasses are broken, what's the probability that of those 5 you pick up, exactly 2 will be broken? (no more, no less)*

The solution is presented as:

$\displaystyle  \frac{{{4}\choose{2}}{{16}\choose{3}}}{{{20}\choose{5}}} \approx 22\%$

While I think I get the logic here, we want to know the probability for picking exactly 2 broken glasses, no matter the order and then we have to pick 3 non-broken of the 5 glasses. We divide these by all combinations of how we can pick 5 glasses from the set of 20.

Now, I tried to apply this to the classic problem, "What's the probability of getting exactly one 6 when throwing two dices at the same time?"

I first calculated this by thinking: There is a 1/6 chance of getting a sixth on the first dice, therefore we need to get 5/6 on the second in order to not get another sixth. Though, the other legal way would be the other way around, so in the end, the probability should be: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{6}\frac{5}{6}\cdot2 = \frac{10}{36}$ (I think).

Now to the question, why can't I use the "formula" presented in the first task to get this probability?

What I tried was basically thinking, there are 12 different sides on the two dices, we will "pick" two of them randomly, and we want exactly 1 of them to be a six and 1 of them to not be a six.

From what I understand, we can also directly translate the above problem but to the die one:

*Imagine that you have 1 box with 12 notes with numbers 1-6, 2 numbers are randomly picked and viewed.  2 of the 12 are sixes, what's the probability that of those 2 you pick up, exactly 1 will be a 6 (no more no less)?*

I tried setting it up similarly to the first problem by expressing it like:

$\displaystyle  \frac{{{2}\choose{1}}{{10}\choose{1}}}{{{12}\choose{2}}} = \frac{10}{33}%$

This is obviously not correct, but I'm missing the idea why this doesn't work like in the first problem, would someone be able to help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have almost the same formula:
\begin{align*}
P(\text{exactly one six}) & = \frac{(\text{choose one die to have the six}) (\text{choose 1 face out of 5 for the other die)}}{(\text{number of ways to roll two dice})} \\
P(\text{exactly one six}) & = \frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{1}}{6^2} \\
P(\text{exactly one six}) & = \frac{2 \times 5}{6^2} = \frac{10}{36} = \frac{5}{18} \approx 27.78 \% \\
\end{align*}

If you really like binomial coefficients, you can rewrite the denominator as (choose 1 face out of six for the first die)(choose 1 face out of 6 for the second die) $= \binom{6}{1}\binom{6}{1}$, which is exactly the same as $6^2$.

#### Regarding your second attempt

You are picking 2 faces out of 12 die faces, but the only "legal" ways to pick two faces that correspond to rolling two dice is if the two faces belong to two different dice. So, your denominator for instance should be $\binom{6}{1}\binom{6}{1}$, not $\binom{12}{2}$.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand why the formula breaks for the dice compared to the box. I liked that you included the correction using the binomial coefficients, as that was making me confused.

Of course we have a total of 36 outcomes, and by those 36 outcomes, we are only allowed to pick 1 of the 2 sixes. When we have picked one, then we are only allowed to pick 1 of the 5 non-sixes left (as we can't pick any number from the first dice of course...)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1**

While there are $12$ numbers, you cannot pick any $2$ of these. For example, can you have $1$ from the first die and $6$ from the first die again? No! The numbers have to come from two different dice.

**Hint 2**

When rolling two dice, there is one way to roll $6-6$. When taking from your box, there is also only one way to take $6-6$.

When rolling two dice, there are two ways to roll $4-5$. When taking from your box, there are four ways to take $4-5$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand where my logic breaks. Those details are very subtle for me but it makes perfect sense.